# overflow auto on child div

Tags: html, css

I have a structure that is similar to modal windows and it looks like this:

```css
.pos_container { 
  display:block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  margin:auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  position:relative;
  top:5%;
  max-height:90%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
 .pos_header { 
  display:block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:15px 20px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  
 }
 .pos_body { 
  display:block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:#fff;
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:100%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="pos_container">
  <div class="pos_header">
   // SOME CONTENT HERE, ALWAYS HAS FIXED HEIGHT
  </div>
  <div class="pos_body">
   // CONTENT IN HERE CAN BE VARIOUS HEIGHT, NEED AUTO-SCROLL 
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've searched the internet and always there is a rule to set the height of `.pos_body` to fixed height, but I need it to fit the visible part of `.pos_container` and in case content of `.pos_body` is overlapping the `.pos_container` then scroll will appear

Comment: Can't you just use overflow: scroll ?

Comment: @TheInterloper in that case i have the scroll-bar but the content of `.pos_body` is not scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a flex container

```css
.pos_container { 
  vertical-align:top;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  margin:auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  position:relative;
  top:5%;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }
 .pos_header { 
  display:block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:15px 20px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  
 }
 .pos_body { 
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:#fff;
  overflow-y:auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pos_container">
  <div class="pos_header">
   // SOME CONTENT HERE, ALWAYS HAS FIXED HEIGHT
  </div>
  <div class="pos_body">
   // CONTENT IN HERE CAN BE VARIOUS HEIGHT, 
      fewfew few<br>
      fe<br>
      fwef<br>
      fwefeweNEED AUTO-SCROLL 
  </div>
 </div>
```